# $N$ is an Alexandroff compactification of $M$ if and only if $M$ is locally compact and separable.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> A metric space $N$ is called *Alexandroff Compactification* of $M$ when $N$ is compact and $N = M_0\cup\{p\}$, where $M_0$ is homeormorphic to $M$ and $p\not\in M_0$. Prove that $N$ is an Alexandroff compactification of $M$ if and only if $M$ is locally compact and separable.

I could only do some work in the ($\implies)$ part, which was proving that $M$ is locally compact. I'll put it here:

Suppose $N$ Alexandroff compactification of $M$. Then, we have $N=M_0 \cup \{\infty\}$  with $M_0$ homeomorphic to $M$ and $N$ compact.We show that $M$ is locally compact. Let $\varphi: M_0 \rightarrow M$ be the function responsible for the homeomorphism. So given $y\in M$, exists $a\in M_0$ such that $\varphi (a) = y$. Consider the ball $B'' = B(y;\epsilon)$ of arbitrary radius in $M$. Since $\varphi$ is continuous, exists $B'=B(a;\delta)$ such that $\varphi(B')\subset B''$. Particularly, we can consider the closed ball $B=B[a;\delta/2]\subset B'$. Since $N$ is compact, we know that $B$ is compact. Again, by continuity we see that $\varphi (B)$ is a compact set in $M$. Noticing  $y\in \varphi(B)\subset M$, we conclude that $M$ is locally compact.

So i'm struggling at proving $M$ is separable. I know that if $M$ is locally compact and connected, then it is separable. But i can't show that $M$ is connected. Perhaps, if it was possible to show that $M_0$ is connected, this would follow. But it does not seems to be the case. Also, i have no good ideas on how to show the reverse implication.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The long line is locally compact and connected, but not separable.

Comment: Do you know that a compact metric space is separable? Then use that to conclude that a $\sigma$-compact locally compact space is separable.